# Find CPU time spend context switching or waking up threads in JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, profiling

I have a multi-threaded application running on a JVM. I would like to know the % CPU time spend on context switching/waking up of threads by the application. The OS in use is GNU/Linux and OSX.

Can I figure it out by profiling the application? If yes, what method should I be looking at that corresponds to context switch time in the profiler output?

Comment: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Counting_with_perf_stat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking a linux question, not a java one. I don't think the JVM has insight into non-voluntary context switches.

This will give you context switch rates for a particular process.

```
pidstat -w -p <pid>
```